# Writing a test class on a Trigger in Salesforce

Tags: unit-testing, triggers, salesforce

I am a complete code noob and need help writing a test class for a trigger in Salesforce.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger UpdateWonAccounts on Opportunity(before Update) {
  Set < Id > accountIds = new Set < Id > ();

  //Collect End user Ids which has won Opportunities
  for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {
    if (o.isWon && o.EndUserAccountName__c != null) {
      accountIds.add(o.EndUserAccountName__c);
    }
  }

  List < Account > lstAccount = new List < Account > ();

  //Iterate and collect all the end user records
  for (Account a : [Select Id, Status__c From Account where Id IN : accountIds]) {
    lstAccount.add(new Account(Id = a.Id, Status__c = true));
  }

  //If there are any accounts then update the records
  if (!lstAccount.isEmpty()) {
    update lstAccount;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need help with writing the code to test this specific trigger?  Or do you just need help with creating a unit test class in general?

Answer (score 1):

Read [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods) and [How To Write A Trigger Test](http://teachmesalesforce.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/how-to-write-a-trigger-test/).

Basically, you want to create a new testmethod that updates (inserts, deletes, undeletes, etc.  depending on your trigger conditions) a record or sObject.

It looks somewhat like this:

```
public class myClass {
    static testMethod void myTest() {
       // Add test method logic to insert and update a new Opportunity here
    }
}
```